# How to avoid repeated data in a select using Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-query-builder

I have this select

[image]

I'm getting all of this information from a table in my database... so I have some repeated rows... I would like to found a kind of if or something to avoid the repeated information in the select... this is my select

```
<div class="form-group row col-xs-3 col-md-4" >
<label class="control-label col-md-4" >Cartera: </label>
<div class="col-md-8">
 <select name="carteras_id" id="carteras_id" class="form-control">
@foreach ($carteras as $cartera)
  <option value="{{ $cartera->carteras_id }}" class="form-control">{{ $cartera->cartera }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
```

This is my query

```
$carteras = DB::table('tbl_perimetros')
            ->join('tbl_lista_carteras', 'tbl_perimetros.carteras_id', '=', 'tbl_lista_carteras.id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: What is your query in your controller?

Comment: I have no idea about these tables but, in general, if you need item_id=>item_name list, you can try this: DB::table("tbl_lista_carteras')->pluck('cartera', 'id'). It seems to me, you've got duplicates because of join. Do you really need this join? If yes, you can apply my query with ->whereHas() condition instead of litetally join().

Comment: It seems you don't need the `tbl_perimetros`'s data, so you can just take values from `tbl_lista_carteras`, and those values will be unique.

Comment: @TsaiKoga I need tbl_perimetros because tbl_lista_carteras is only for see... The value carteras_id is from the table tbl_perimetros

Comment: @Oscar I think `carteras_id` is as same as  `tbl_lista_carteras`'s id, because `tbl_lista_carteras`'s id is the primary_key, and `carteras_id` is the foreign_key.

Comment: @TsaiKoga yes.. you are right... carteras_id is the foreing key which is doing a match with tbl_lista_carteras 's id... so.. I would like to filter this $cartera->cartera... cartera from tbl_lista_carteras... how could I do that?

Comment: @Oscar posted answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `tbl_lista_carteras` **has many** `tbl_perimetros`, so when you use `join` to these two table, the `tbl_lista_carteras` datas will be duplicataed, and you only need to display the `tbl_lista_carteras`'s datas, you can get them from `tbl_lista_carteras` directly:

```php
$carteras = DB::table('tbl_lista_carteras')
    ->select('id','cartera')
    ->get();
```

And display them in your view:

```php
@foreach ($carteras as $cartera)
  <option value="{{ $cartera->id }}" class="form-control">{{ $cartera->cartera }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: this works!! thanks.. but what about If I would like to edit my table tbl_perimetros.. because with this method I only edit  tbl_lista carteras.. and in my database I didn't have any change in tbl_perimetros

Comment: I think this part only display datas, Do u mean choose the option for edit table?

Comment: So I need to edit carteras_id which is from tbl_perimetros

Comment: @Oscar `<select name="carteras_id" id="carteras_id" class="form-control">` before `@foreach`, you have named `carteras_id` for the select_tag, when you choose the option, and submit, laravel will receive `request->input('carteras_id')`, so you can edit `tbl_perimetros`

Comment: hey! If I have three related tables how could I do, like in this case..... $asesors = DB::table('tbl_perimetros')
                ->join('tbl_equipo_postventaatcs', 'tbl_perimetros.postventaatc_id', '=', 'tbl_equipo_postventaatcs.id')
                ->join('users', 'tbl_equipo_postventaatcs.asesor_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->get();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208648/discussion-between-tsaikoga-and-oscar).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$carteras = DB::table('tbl_perimetros')
    ->join('tbl_lista_carteras', 'tbl_perimetros.carteras_id', '=', 'tbl_lista_carteras.id')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

Comment: this doesn't work because I have some repeated information in tbl_perimetros

Comment: Ok, and Why don't you start your query directly from table `tbl_lista_carteras`? $carteras = DB::table('tbl_lista_carteras')
    ->join('tbl_perimetros', 'tbl_perimetros.carteras_id', '=', 'tbl_lista_carteras.id')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unique('cartera')` on collection to get only records with unique values in cartera column

```
$unique = $carteras->unique('cartera')
```

Comment: If you don't need any of the repeated informations in your view, I would put it in controller and send only unique values to the view

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `group By` in your *Query*:

```
$carteras = DB::table('tbl_perimetros')
            ->join('tbl_lista_carteras', 'tbl_perimetros.carteras_id', '=', 'tbl_lista_carteras.id')
            ->groupBy('tbl_perimetros.carteras_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: I obtained this .... SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bduempresas.tbl_perimetros.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `tbl_perimetros` inner join `tbl_lista_carteras` on `tbl_perimetros`.`carteras_id` = `tbl_lista_carteras`.`id` group by `tbl_perimetros`.`carteras_id`)

Comment: Try add this after `groupBy`:
`->select('tbl_perimetros.*, tbl_lista_carteras.*')`

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'tbl_perimetros.*, tbl_lista_carteras' (SQL: select `tbl_perimetros`.`*, tbl_lista_carteras`.* from `tbl_perimetros` inner join `tbl_lista_carteras` on `tbl_perimetros`.`carteras_id` = `tbl_lista_carteras`.`id` group by `tbl_perimetros`.`carteras_id`)